# Replace a line in a file with Ansible, while ensuring that line is present

Tags: ansible

I’m using Ansible and I need to replace a line in a file. The file is a logrotate configuration file for apache `/etc/logrotate.d/apache2`. Before modification, the line reads

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
```

which I want to replace with

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log /var/log/apache2/*/*.log {
```

I’d rather not rewrite the whole file, not to affect the content of the configuration.

I can do this with the `lineinfile` module:

```
- name: Configure logrotate for Apache
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/logrotate.d/apache2
    regexp: '^(/var/log/apache2/\*\.log) (?:/var/log/apache2/\*/\*\.log )?{$'
    # The backrefs option is required to ensure the line won’t just be 
    # added, breaking the syntax of the file…
    backrefs: yes
    line: '\1 /var/log/apache2/*/*.log {'
```

Unfortunately, this task succeeds (with no action) if the regexp is not matched in the configuration file. I’d rather have it fail.

The solution I found is to check the configuration with an extra task:

```
- name: Check logrotate’s configuration for Apache
  command: egrep '^/var/log/apache2/\*\.log /var/log/apache2/\*/\*\.log {$' /etc/logrotate.d/apache2
  changed_when: no
```

This seems to work, but I’m unhappy with the duplication of the regexp…

Is there a better way to change a line while failing if that line is not present?

Note that I’m currently stuck with (the quite ancient) Ansible 2.2, but I’m still interested by solutions that work with newer versions.

Comment: What do you mean with "failing if that line is not present". Should the play, or host be terminated?

Comment: @VladimirBotka Sorry, I’m still quite new to Ansible, and I don’t understand the difference between terminating the play or the host… I guess I would want to get the same behavior I get with the `fail` module or a task with `failed_when: yes`. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3):

> Q: *"Before modification, the line reads*

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
```

> *which I want to replace with*

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log /var/log/apache2/*/*.log {
```

A: The task below does the job with [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html)

```
- lineinfile:
    path: /etc/logrotate.d/apache2
    regexp: '^(/var/log/apache2/\*\.log)\s+{$'
    line: '\1 /var/log/apache2/*/*.log {'
    backrefs: yes
```

> Q: *"Is there a better way to change a line while failing if that line is not present?"*

A: 
The task below fails when *pattern* is not in the configuration file

```
   - fail:
        msg: Pattern not in file
      when: not lookup('file', my_conf).splitlines()|
            select('match', pattern)|list
      vars:
        pattern: '^/var/log/apache2/\*\.log\s+{$'
        my_conf: '/etc/logrotate.d/apache2'

   - replace:
       path: /etc/logrotate.d/apache2
       regexp: '^(/var/log/apache2/\*\.log)\s+{$'
       replace: '\1 /var/log/apache2/*/*.log {'
```

Comment: I've added the task to fail when the pattern is not in the file.

Comment: I must be missing something, but I still don’t see how this is better (not that I think it is worse, it just looks equivalent to me) than what I did with lineinfile and a grep command. You also need 2 tasks and the regexp is duplicated.

Comment: As for my `command: grep` task being OS-specific, you certainly have a point.

Comment: You're right. *lineinfile* with *backrefs* works fine. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just deleted the comments that were not relevant anymore.